# MLP with Time Series DATA and cross-validation

Tags: r, time-series, cross-validation, mlp

I use tsCV in the forecast package to evaluate forecasts of different models over different forecasting horizons.

However, when I run the following multivariate mlp, e_mlp consists out of NA NA NA.

I would very much appreciate any help.

See below the minimal reproducible example.

```
library(forecast)
library(RSNNS)
xreg = as.matrix(cbind(1:120, 121:240),ncol=2)
y <- as.ts(1:120)
f <- function(xreg, y,h) {
  X <- xreg[1:length(y)]
  newX <- xreg[1:(length(y)+h)]
  fit <- mlp(y,xreg=matrix(X))
  forecast(fit, xreg=matrix(newX), h=h)
}
e_mlp <- tsCV(xreg = xreg, y= y, f, h= 15)
mse_mlp <- (colMeans(e_mlp^2, na.rm=TRUE))
```

when I leave out the cross-validation it works:

```
h = 1
xreg = as.matrix(cbind(1:120, 121:240, rnorm(120, mean = 0, sd = 1),ncol=3))
y <- as.ts(rnorm(120, mean = 0, sd = 1))
X <- xreg[1:length(y)]
newX <- xreg[1:(length(y)+h)]
fit <- mlp(y,xreg=matrix(X))
forecast(fit, xreg=matrix(newX), h=h)
```

Comment: Your second, supposedly working code is not working for me. It throws an error at `fit <- mlp(y,xreg=matrix(X))`.

Comment: I am sorry.  Does this work for you? '''h =1
xreg = as.matrix(cbind(1:120, 121:240, rnorm(120, mean = 0, sd = 1),ncol=3))
y <- as.ts(rnorm(120, mean = 0, sd = 1))
X <- xreg[1:length(y)]
newX <- xreg[1:(length(y)+h)]
fit <- mlp(y,xreg=matrix(X))
forecast(fit, xreg=matrix(newX), h=h) ''' I also changed the above example.

Comment: No, still not working. You should make sure to provide code that is reproducible. Otherwise it is difficult to help.